# relationship between controller and view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to mvc, mvp or whatever you want to call them. Right now I try to implement a `ReservationController` where the user first selects a date and then gets a list of suitable time suggestions. As you should know, the suggestions depend on the selected date. This is where my problem / question starts. Should I:

1) Put an event in the View interface like `DateChanged` and then subscribe to it in the controller?

2) Call `UpdateSuggestions` on the controller from my asp page, when the selected date changes. (then I must make the controller method public)

Or

3) Update the suggestions in the constructor of the controller.

Regards and thx for help

eric

Comment: Please provide a code sample and which version of MVC are you using?

Comment: Is the date selection done via a link?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Based on `"mvc, mvp or whatever you want to call them"`, a good first step would be to go the effort of finding out which framework you are using and the differences between it and others that you may be getting confused with.

Comment: The controler must observe the model not the view ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller#Concepts

Answer (score 7):

You need to get out of the control events mind-frame which drives ASP.NET web forms. Although it is technically possible to accomplish things this way I would suggest going down a different route.

You need to return a view to the user which lets them enter a date into a form. They then post the form back to the server and another action method handles this post. This method gets the list of time suggestions and returns a view with these times as its model.

Take a look here for some decent videos on MVC basics: http://www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: Exactly, MVC is request-response driven, since HTTP is stateless. I personally think WebForms guffed up web development, but that's the cost to let the skilled VB6 devs hit the ground running for the web.

Comment: Very true - I think MVC has done and is doing huge amounts to increase the skill-base of ASP.NET web devs. Even if WebForms continues at strength, there will be a greater number of people capable of properly understanding what it's doing. Saying that - all the devs I know who use MVC now hate working with WebForms.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some great examples of ASP.Net MVC that are great reading for anyone just getting started.

http://www.asp.net/mvc

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc3-part1-cs

These two samples include books that take you step by step through creating an MVC project:

http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/

http://www.asp.net/mvc/samples/mvc-music-store

This may not answer your question directly BUT going throught these samples should help make it clear how MVC works and specifically how to use it in ASP.Net. :-)

Here's also a little background on the MVC pattern.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649643.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think your are misunderstanding how MVC works.

If you are not clear on how MVC works it would be worth checking out something like [nerd dinner](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm) and [Scott Gu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/03/09/free-video-training-asp-net-mvc-3-features.aspx).

You could have your dates link to an action like below to process this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult YourAction(DateTime date)
        {
            // Add action logic here
            Manager suggestions = new Manager();
            var suggestions =suggestions.UpdateSuggestions(date)

            // create view model
            MyModel model= new MyModel(suggestions);
            return View(model);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put a link or form in your view that points to a URL that passes the date to an action in the controller.
This action should take the date as a parameter, fetch the data for that date, and pass it to a separate view that renders the data.

---

You should learn the basics of HTTP and web pages, as well as the underlying design of ASP.Net MVC.
Writing code in a framework or system that you don't understand is a recipe for frustration and disaster.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but your knowledge in asp.net mvc is very very poor. Better to get some knowledge better, or you cannot make it work. But anyways

1) There do not exist events in views in mvc
2) View does not call contstructor on controller
3) see first two